# Todo me sale en negrita

Tags: html

tengo una pequeña duda y es que cuando ejecuto el documento HTML en el navegador me sale todo en **negrita** y es algo que me tiene desesperado.

Nota: trabajo con notepad++

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Diría que el error está en tu HTML/CSS, por lo tanto sugiero que incluyas una muestra del mismo en la pregunta. (un [mcve]).

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La pregunta asi como esta, es incontestable porque no sabemos nada, salvo que parece que tenes un tag mal cerrado... no hay mucho mas para decirte a menos que uses el boton [edit] y pongas tu codigo

Comment: Hola bienvenido!, es muy probable que tengas todo el código o parte de el englobado en las etiquetas <Strong> y por eso te sale todo en negrita. Si eres tan amable podrías añadir tu código para que le demos un vistazo?